# Custom Camera Application for Android: Adjusting Colors in Real Time

Tags: android, colors, camera

I am considering an application which would adjust the hue/saturation (overall color spectrum) of the camera input in real time. Are current phones (such as the Galaxy S3) powerful enough to allow for real-time color filtering/adjustments of the live camera image, or am I forced to apply the color shift / image manipulation post processing like most of the apps I see?

Essentially I need to convert the real-time image feed to a different color spectrum and display the updated image in real time prior to "snapping a picture". Any feedback on how to do this in real time prior to a "snap" would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know, but take a look at the "Paper Camera" app, which does something completely different (yet, the same).

Comment: Excellent reference; this shows I can do what I'm trying to accomplish. Now for the question; do I start processing the camera input by hand, or is there an existing library out there which I can purchase/apply to act as the real-time image processing system?

Comment: Take a look at EffectFactory library inbuilt with API 14 onwards.